# standard deviation of an arbitrary number of numbers using bc or other standard utilities

Tags: bash, variables, standard-deviation

Is there some trick that would allow one to use bc (or some other standard utility) to return the standard deviation of an arbitrary number of numbers? For convenience, let's say that the numbers are stored in a Bash variable in the following way:

```
myNumbers="0.556
1.456
45.111
7.812
5.001"
```

So, the answer I'm looking for would be in a form such as the following:

```
standardDeviation="$(echo "${myNumbers}" | <insert magic here>)"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
standardDeviation=$(
    echo "$myNumbers" |
        awk '{sum+=$1; sumsq+=$1*$1}END{print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}'
)
echo $standardDeviation
```

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Math::NumberCruncher;

my @data = qw/
    0.556
    1.456
    45.111
    7.812
    5.001
/;

print Math::NumberCruncher::StandardDeviation(\@data);
```

### Output

```
16.7631
```

Comment: That's a nice little awk cycle there and, naturally, one can't argue against the sensibility of using Perl here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I get 'syntax error at or near *' because of the `**2`, replacing it with `*(sum/NR)` fixes this.

Comment: Nice. A note that this is population standard deviation vs sample standard deviation...

Answer (score 5):

Or use GNU Octave (which can much more than simple std):

```
standardDeviation="$(echo "${myNumbers}" | octave --eval 'disp(std(scanf("%f")))')"
echo $standardDeviation
```

Outputs

```
18.742
```

Comment: At least on my system, the `octave` command briefly launches a graphical application named octave-gui unless I add the `--no-window-system` flag. You can replace `std(scanf("%f"))` with `std(scanf("%f"),1)` to calculate the population standard deviation instead of the sample standard deviation.

Comment: @nisetama the GUI is default since GNU Octave 4.0.x and was changed back for Octave 5.0.x

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/std.html

Answer (score 5):

Population standard deviation:

```
jq -s '(add/length)as$a|map(pow(.-$a;2))|add/length|sqrt'
ruby -e'a=readlines.map(&:to_f);puts (a.map{|x|(x-a.reduce(:+)/a.length)**2}.reduce(:+)/a.length)**0.5'
jq -s '(map(.*.)|add/length)-pow(add/length;2)|sqrt'
awk '{x+=$0;y+=$0^2}END{print sqrt(y/NR-(x/NR)^2)}'
```

In `awk`, `^` is in POSIX but `**` is not. `**` is supported by `gawk` and `nawk` but not by `mawk`.

Sample standard deviation (the first two commands are the same as the first two commands above, but `length` was replaced with `length-1`):

```
jq -s '(add/length)as$a|map(pow(.-$a;2))|add/(length-1)|sqrt'
ruby -e'a=readlines.map(&:to_f);puts (a.map{|x|(x-a.reduce(:+)/a.length)**2}.reduce(:+)/(a.length-1))**0.5'
R -q -e 'sd(scan("stdin"))'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, 8 years later, with **gnuplot**:

```
echo "${myNumbers}" | gnuplot -e 'stats "-" nooutput; print STATS_stddev'
16.7630779918248
```

By way of explanation, I am getting **gnuplot** to run the `stats` function on the data on its `stdin`, suppressing the normal output and printing just the standard deviation.

---

Related, but not really part of answer... you can also generate lots of other statistics, like median, kurtosis and skew, quartiles, maxima, minima like this:

```
echo "${myNumbers}" | gnuplot -e 'stats "-"'
```

**Sample Output**

```
* FILE: 
  Records:           5
  Out of range:      0
  Invalid:           0
  Header records:    0
  Blank:             0
  Data Blocks:       1

* COLUMN: 
  Mean:              11.9872
  Std Dev:           16.7631
  Sample StdDev:     18.7417
  Skewness:           1.4125
  Kurtosis:           3.1303
  Avg Dev:           13.2495
  Sum:               59.9360
  Sum Sq.:         2123.4687

  Mean Err.:          7.4967
  Std Dev Err.:       5.3010
  Skewness Err.:      1.0954
  Kurtosis Err.:      2.1909

  Minimum:            0.5560 [0]
  Maximum:           45.1110 [2]
  Quartile:           1.4560 
  Median:             5.0010 
  Quartile:           7.8120
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ myNumbers=$(echo "0.556 1.456 45.111 7.812 5.001" | tr " " "\n")
```

First decide if you need [sample standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Sample_standard_deviation_of_metabolic_rate_of_Northern_Fulmars) vs [population standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Population_standard_deviation_of_grades_of_eight_students) of those numbers.

Population standard deviation (the function [STDEV.P](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-P-function-6e917c05-31a0-496f-ade7-4f4e7462f285) in Excel) requires the entire population of datum. In Excel, text or blanks are skipped.

It is easily calculated on a rolling basis in `awk`:

```
$ echo "$myNumbers" | awk '$1+0==$1 {sum+=$1; sumsq+=$1*$1; cnt++}
                           END{print sumsq/cnt; print sqrt(sumsq/cnt - (sum/cnt)**2)}'
16.7631
```

Or in `Ruby`:

```
$ echo "$myNumbers" | ruby -e 'arr=$<.read.split(/\s/).map { |e| Float(e) rescue nil }.compact
                             sumsq=arr.inject(0) { |acc, e| acc+=e*e }
                             p (sumsq/arr.length - (arr.sum/arr.length)**2)**0.5'
16.76307799182477
```

For a sample standard deviation (the function [STDEV.S](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/STDEV-S-function-7d69cf97-0c1f-4acf-be27-f3e83904cc23) in Excel and ignoring text or blanks) You need to have the entire sample collected first since the mean is used against each value in the sample.

In `awk`:

```
$ echo "$myNumbers" | 
     awk 'function sdev(array) {
     for (i=1; i in array; i++)
        sum+=array[i]
     cnt=i-1
     mean=sum/cnt
     for (i=1; i in array; i++)  
        sqdif+=(array[i]-mean)**2
     return (sqdif/(cnt-1))**0.5
     }
     $1+0==$1 {sum1[++cnt]=$1} 
     END {print sdev(sum1)}' 
18.7417
```

Or in Ruby:

```
$ ruby -lane 'BEGIN{col1=[]}
            col1 << Float($F[0]) rescue nil
            END {col1.compact
                 mean=col1.sum / col1.length
                 p (col1.inject(0){ |acc, e| acc+(e-mean)**2 } / 
                        (col1.length-1))**0.5
              }' <(echo "$myNumbers")
18.741690950925424
```