# How to calculate the standard deviation of a column value by AWK in Bash?

Tags: bash, awk, mean, calculated-columns, standard-deviation

I have a data looks like:

```
condition A
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
```

then I calculated the mean value of this condition is 0.875 by using a **awk** command as below: (basically it's just sum all value divided by number of row)
Mean: `cat $a.csv | awk -F"," '$1=="Picture" && $2=="1" && $3=="hit" && $4==1{c++} END {print c/16}'`

My question is how to calculate standard deviation of this condition?
I already know SD of this condition is 0.3415650255 calculated by EXCEL...

And I already tried out several awk commands but still cannot get this result right...

```
cat $a.csv | awk -F"," '$1=="Picture" && $2=="2" && $3=="hit" && $4=="2"{c++} END {c=0;ssq=0;for (i=1;i<=16;i++){c+=$i;ssq+=$i**2}; print (ssq/16-(c/16)**2)**0.5}'

cat $a.csv | awk -F"," '$1=="Picture" && $2=="2" && $3=="hit" && $4==2{c++} {delta=$4-(c/16); avg==delta/16;mean2+=delta*($4-avg);} END { avg=c/16; printf "mean: %f. standard deviation: %f \n", avg, sqrt(mean2/16) }'

cat $a.csv | awk -F"," '$1=="Picture" && $2=="2" && $3=="hit" && $4==2{c++} END { avg=c/16; printf "mean: %f. standard deviation: %f \n", avg, sqrt((c/16-1)-(c/16-1)^2)  }'
```

I still cannot get the right standard deviation in this condition.
Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Btw.: `awk` can read files itself.

Comment: your code is skipping all your input becuase you don't have `"Picture"` as the first field (etc, etc). Please conform your code to work with your simple, sample data (yes, good idea!). Good luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15101429/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall *how* to calculate [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). You need all the values since you need individual differences from the mean.

Doing manually first, in Excel:

[image]

Now you can implement that easily in any language that has arrays and math functions.

In `awk`:

```
$ echo "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0" | tr " " "\n" > file
$ awk 'function sdev(array) {
     for (i=1; i in array; i++)
        sum+=array[i]
     cnt=i-1
     mean=sum/cnt
     for (i=1; i in array; i++)  
        sqdif+=(array[i]-mean)**2
     return (sqdif/(cnt-1))**0.5
     }
     {sum1[FNR]=$1} 
     END {print sdev(sum1)}' file
0.341565
```

Comment: I tried your command like this: `awk 'function sdev(array) {for (i=1; i in array; i++) { sum+=array[i]} {cnt=i-1} {mean=sum/cnt} {for (i=1; i in array; i++) {sqdif+=(array[i]-mean)**2} return (sqdif/(cnt-1))**0.5} {sum1[FNR]=$1} {print sdev(sum1)}}' t1.csv` Although it did not occur any error, but it did not print out anything as well... Can you spot where I miss? Thanks

Comment: If you really have a `.csv` file you probably need to change the field separator to `awk -F"," 'the rest of the awk program...'`

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but still didn't work out...Do you think the csv file is a problem? I saw you echo newline into file, may be it's a problem as well?`cat t1.csv
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
`

Comment: Add example data to your question.

Comment: like this: `cat t1.csv 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1`

Comment: That is not a csv file. It is space separated. Use the `tr` that I used to translate the spaces into `\n` or use `split` in `awk`